OTU data into box plots
I am trying to create a box plot of the relative abundance of a taxa controlled for a Vitamin D condition.
For example a boxplot with the relative abundance of Bifidobacterium, one boxplot for Vitamin D supplementation and another for one without Vitamin D supplementation
I have OTU data that looks like this:
 label        SampleID numOtus Otu001 Otu002 Otu003 Otu004 
1      VD25FE8951OGPRO     347      1   1388   1032     17          
1       VD25FE8946OGPRO     347     36   5600   1170    15     

I have been successful in creating a stacked bar chart.
However, I am not able to figure out how to create a box plot based on the taxa identification.
Is there a way for me to convert a stacked bar chart into boxplots based on Taxa when controlled for the marker (VD or NXX) in the SampleID column?
I have tried the following:
a<-StackedBarPlot(OTU=Data.BabyEBF[,-c(1:3)],TaxName=TaxName)
library(tidyr)

#Reshape data from wide to long format
long_data <- gather(a, key = "Category", value = "Value", -Sample)

library(ggplot2)

#Create box plot using ggplot2
ggplot(long_data, aes(x = Category, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Category", y = "Value",
       title = "Box plot of Values by Category") +
  theme_minimal()

This is the stacked bar chart appearance for reference:

